# Should a gerund phrase have an article?

Tags: articles, gerunds

A. the effects of **the** spraying of Matacil...

B. the effects of spraying of Matacil...

Would you please tell me if you feel any difference in meaning between those, and which of them could be treated as a good English?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using the article implies we're talking about some *specific* spraying process, which would normally entail the further implication that said spraying *has in fact taken place*. Without the article it's possible no such spraying has ever been done, and you're just talking about possible effects if it *was* carried out.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In *the spraying of something*, there is no gerund, only a noun phrase involving a deverbal noun with a prepositional phrase. In *spraying something*, we have an actual verb with an object, so this is the gerund-participle. Gerunds don’t take noun things; they take verb things; for example, you can apply *quickly* to the gerund but not to the deverbal noun, which of course requires an adjective.

Comment: Thanks. However, what about my specific question(s)?